# Jquery UI Sortable to check which table rows are changed

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am facing a problem while using the Jquery UI. The page contains many tables. All tables rows can be sorted. I am using a Jquery UI Library for this purpose.

Whenever rows of a particular table are sorted or dragged, I need to send an ajax call to the server. For that, I need to check which table rows are dragged or sorted, so I can process only that table as the page contains many other tables as well.

The code below makes all body sortable. And whenever the rows are dragged it trigger the update_arrangement() method. In the update_arrangement() function, I need to check which table's rows are changed or dragged.

```
$('tbody').sortable({
    update: function () {
        update_arrangement();
    }
});
```

// update_arrangement() function

```
function update_arrangement() {
    var priority = [];
    $("#tbody tr").each(function (i) {
        if (i != 0) {
            var sequence = {id: $(this).find("td:first").text(), 
             priority: i};
            console.log(sequence);
            priority.push(sequence);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/email/update/sequence",
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'priority': priority
        },

        success: function (data) {
            console.log("updated");
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I would advise you make use of the parameters of your callback function. If nothing else, pass `$(this)` or `this` to your function so you have some reference to sortable that was updated. Your example is lacking the HTML portion, so there is no way to really know how to improve things.

Comment: Thanks, @Twisty, I just solved the issue using the callback function parameters.